# reading a variable from the user in an expect script

Tags: expect

Below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
echo "enter unique id" 
read test
mkdir -p  /evoting_test/$test
        spawn scp -r abc@10.150.10.104:/shareddata/was/l1/*.pdf /rishabh/$test/
        set pass "abc123"
        expect {
                password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
                }
```

I am getting error:

```
invalid command name "echo"
    while executing
"echo "enter uNIQUE id" "
    (file "./scp_test.sh" line 2)
```

It is not reading variable from user and use that variable in command

Comment: Please, in the future, check the preview to make your formatting is correct before posting your question.

Comment: That said, as to your question: `echo` and `read`, like `mkdir`, are not valid expect commands. expect is not bash; you can't use a `#!/usr/bin/expect` shebang, and then write code that isn't in the expect language (itself a superset of TCL) inside of it.

Comment: ...and since the problem happens before you get to the scp command, there's no reason for scp to be part of the title (or part of the question, for that matter): the same issue would happen even without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "expect" way to do that is:

```
send_user "enter unique id: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set test $expect_out(1,string)
send_user "you said $test\n"
```

Since expect extends [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), you could use:

```
puts -nonewline "enter unique id: "
flush stdout
gets stdin test
puts "you said $test"
```

Additionally, you'll get an error for `mkdir` -- that's an external command. You can do one of:

```
exec mkdir -p /evoting_test/$test   # invoke the external command
file mkdir /evoting_test/$test      # use the builtin
```

See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm

Comment: It Works Thanks for your help

Comment: is it possible to suppress echoing the input so that you may prompt for a password that gets captured into the variable (without the password being visible on the screen)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way to solve this out would be to separate the two files each of which is using a different interpreter as per its requirement.

1. First File: will contain the code to scp all the pdf files to the desired location and you can read the destination location in this script as well.
2. Use expect to run the above file and get your work done.